# Kotlin setOnClickListener syntax using lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

When setting up a click listener in Kotlin, we can write:

```kotlin
rollButton.setOnClickListener(
    object: View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            rollDice();
        }
    }
)
```

After SAM conversion, we can write:

```kotlin
rollButton.setOnClickListener({ v -> rollDice() })
```

But I noticed that kotlin also accepts:

```kotlin
rollButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() { v -> rollDice() })
```

as well as

```kotlin
rollButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v -> rollDice() })
```

I want to know what is happening here? I mean `setOnClickListener` is supposed to take an implementation of `OnClickListener` using something like Anonymous class or SAM shorthand. Is this some kind of intermediate stage or what?

Any explanation or link to resources is highly appreciated.

Comment: _"Kotlin can convert any lambda expression whose signature matches the signature of the interface's single method into an instance of a class that implements the interface"_ ([source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions)) and _"If [a] lambda is the only argument to [a function], the parentheses can be omitted"_ ([source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)).

Comment: Hence why you can write things like `rollButton.setOnClickListener({ v -> rollDice() })` or even `rollButton.setOnClickListener { v -> rollDice() }`

Comment: Now that I understood what SAM conversion actually is, how is `rollButton.setOnClickListener({ v -> rollDice() })` working? The name of interface is missing!

Comment: The compiler knows that `setOnClickListener` expects an `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For these examples, let the interface be:

```
fun interface IntUser {
    fun use(value: Int)
}
```

SAM conversion lets you use the interface's name like a constructor that takes the lambda as an argument.

```
val x = IntUser({ println(it) })
```

[Trailing lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas) allows you to move the lambda outside the parentheses like your second example:

```
val y = IntUser() { println(it) }
```

When using trailing lambda syntax when the lambda is the only parameter, you can omit the parentheses, like in your third example:

```
val z = IntUser { println(it) }
```

Finally, the other thing SAM conversion can do is let you pass a bare lambda in place of an interface parameter. It can infer the type from the function argument:

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    rollDice()
}
```

Here we are using the lambda as the sole parameter, so we are also employing trailing lambda syntax and omission of the empty parentheses.

Comment: Great explanation, maybe only missing that this only applies for functional interfaces.

Comment: @m0skit0, SAM or Single Abstract Method interface is otherwise known as Functional interface, isn't it?

Comment: That’s true for Java interfaces, but for Kotlin interfaces you also have to put `fun` before `interface` for it to be considered a functional interface and allow lambda conversion.

Comment: Yeah, I just mean that instead of "let you pass a bare lambda in place of an interface parameter" it would be more correct to say "let you pass a bare lambda in place of a functional interface parameter", and so on.

Comment: I was responding to OP.